# Outputting an error when a Char/String is typed instead of an Integer

Tags: java, input, output, java.util.scanner

```
package project2;

import java.util.*;

public class Project2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String Name;
    int age;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter your age : ");
    age = input.nextInt();
    if (age>=16){
        System.out.println("Your good to go");}
    else if ((age>=1)&&(age<=15)){       
        System.out.println("Your not allowed to Procced");}
    else{
        System.out.println("Out of range");}
    }
}
```

Sorry newbie :/ . So i have this problem when i typed a letter in "Enter you age" is shows

Enter your age : q

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)

at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)

at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)

at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)

at project2.Project2.main(Project2.java:14)

Java Result: 1

I want if i typed any letter it shows "Invalid input". Can anyone help me? [ Sorry bad english ]

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: `q` is not an `int` , `nextInt()` expects an integer right ?

Comment: I want if typed a letter it shows "Invalid Input"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if i typed any letter it shows "Invalid input". Can anyone help me?

Catch the exception and print the message, like below -

```
try{
    System.out.print("Enter your age : ");
    age = input.nextInt();
}catch(RuntimeException ex){
    System.out.println("Invalid input");
}
```

Comment: Hey Subhrajyoti Majumder! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever asked someone about his age and he told you: `q`? It's not an age and not an `int`.

You're getting the *exception* because [`nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29):

> `throws InputMismatchException` - **if the next token does not match the
>   Integer regular expression**, or is out of range

Answer (score 0):

Before reading the int with `input.nextInt()`, check with `input.hasNextInt()`, which will read just enough to tell whether it's an int or not (but leave it for nextInt to read; it doesn't mess up anything) and then return that.

```
if(!input.hasNextInt())
    System.out.println("Not an int");
else
{
    int age = input.nextInt();
    // other code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int age = 0;
        boolean isContinue = true;
        do {
            try {
                System.out.print("Enter your age : ");
                String age1 = input.next();
                age = Integer.parseInt(age1);
                isContinue = false;
                if (age >= 16) {
                    System.out.println("Your good to go");
                } else if ((age >= 1) && (age <= 15)) {
                    System.out.println("Your not allowed to Procced");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Out of range");
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Not an valid age");
            }
        } while (isContinue);

        System.out.println("other code");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the input as String and check if it is a number

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your age : ");
    String rawAge = input.next();
    try {
        int age = Integer.parseInt(rawAge);
        System.out.println("Age: " + age);
        // Do something with age
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input for age");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use exception handling

```
import java.util.*;

public class crack
{       
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String Age;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your age : ");
        Age = input.nextLine();
        try
        {
            int age = Integer.parseInt(Age);
            if (age>=16)
            {
                System.out.println("Your good to go");
            }
            else if ((age>=1)&&(age<=15))
            {       
                System.out.println("Your not allowed to Procced");
            }
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nFE)
        {
            System.out.println("out of range");}
        }
    }
}
```